# Is there any jQuery mobile plugin for making a tile list?

Tags: layout, jquery-mobile

I want to make a list like this http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/lists/lists-search.html ,  but instead of using an standard vertical list, I want to use a tile based list.

Do you know any plugin that makes this? If you don't, is there a way you think you can do it without breaking jquery mobile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with just a bit of CSS:

```
.custom-ul .ui-li {
    width  : 200px;
    height : 200px;
    float  : left;
}
/*jQuery Mobile adds a `.ui-btn-inner` element that also has the `.ul-li` class, so it needs to be reset after the changes made above*/
.custom-ul .ui-li .ui-btn-inner {
    width : 100%;
}
```

This sets a specific height/width for list items, then floats them so they stack in a grid-style, and then it resets the inner-div of the list-items. Notice the `.custom-ul` part of the selector, this makes it so you can still have standard lists but when you want a "grid-style" list you can just add the `.custom-ul` class to the `<ul data-role="listview">` element.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ykEtD/ (It's the same list output twice, the first one has the `.custom-ul` class)

Note that you may need to tweak other CSS to get exactly what you want, but this will be a good starting place for you.

Comment: Looks like it works. I couldn't test it yet, but looks great! Thanks!!